# Opening a file of any extension in an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application in which i need to open any files in standard formats such as .doc/docx/.csv/.txt/.xls in an iframe . How can I achieve this ? I tried using the sample code below but it is not opening all the file formats in the iframe. I am getting some XML error.

```
var ext = GetExtension(fileName);
        switch (ext)
        {
            case "pdf":
                Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                break;
            case "htm":
            case "html":
                Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                break;
            case "txt":
                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                break;
            case "doc":
                Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case "xls":
            case "csv":
                Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case "ppt":
            case "pps":
                Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
                break;
            default:
                Response.ContentType = "Application/unknown";
                break;
        }
        if (Response.ContentType != "Application/unknown")
        {
            Response.Flush();
            Response.WriteFile(fileName);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: One thing to try, instead of `Response.Flush();` use `Response.Clear();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this header

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.[EXTENSION]")
```

you should replace the exact [EXTENSION] here. like for pdf

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf")
```

and then you can also write

```
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
```

Where filename is the full path to the file